# MySQLi Error with a simple WHERE clause SELECT statement

Tags: mysqli, where-clause, fetch, sql

I have a simple mysqli query which fails to run when I set the where condition to a string like the below code (option='title'), however if I used an integer instead (id=1) it works!

here is the code:

```
$db_name = "gp";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_host = "localhost";
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

if($sql_title = $mysqli->query("SELECT value FROM options WHERE option='title' LIMIT 1")){
    if($sql_title->num_rows > 0){
        $row_title = $sql_title->fetch_object();
        $title = $row_title->value;
        echo $title;
    }
    else
        echo "No Title!";
}
else
    echo $mysqli->error;

$mysqli->close();
```

my database structure

```
--------------------------
| id | option |  value   |
--------------------------
| 1  | title  | hello    |
| 2  | image  | logo.jpg |
```

the error
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysqli::query(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option='title' LIMIT 1' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`option` is a reserved word in mysql, you have to put it in backticks.

```
if($sql_title = $mysqli->query("SELECT value FROM options WHERE `option`='title' LIMIT 1")){
```

Answer (score 0):

`option` is a [keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as a column identifier, make sure to always enclose it in backticks:

```
SELECT value FROM options WHERE `option`='title' LIMIT 1
```